# Why was I not awarded the maximum speed objective?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

In the scenario, Island Hopping for RCT3, I placed a roller coaster than meets the requirements for the apprentice objectives, however, I was not awarded the max speed one even though my coaster does meet the criteria. I have done test runs (by selecting the yellow circle) and the coaster has been open for a few runs as well (by selecting the green circle).

So my question; why did the game not award me the objective and how do I fix it?

[image: Island Hopping Objective]

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other coaster in your park that doesn't meet this requirement?

Comment: @StrixVaria Positive. This scenario is very difficult and you have to start from scratch, so this is the first roller coaster (or any ride for that matter) that I placed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Maximum speed" in this case means "cannot go over the listed speed", meaning you need to ensure that all roller coasters are **under**  the listed speed.

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't say "minimum maximum speed"  and judging by the scenerio description of "laid back and chillin'", Your max speed on any ride must not exceed the limit.